# Makehuman 1.1.1 use mhx2 no rigify on export?

Tags: rigify, makehuman

I see new features in Makehuman 1.1.1 using mhx2
only has export options with just Poses

Where can i use rigify as previous version ?

i don't see any rigify or FK/IK in blender

Answer (score 1):

While importing there is a override exported data, check that and in that column at bottom you'll see rig type ,in that you can choose either exported rigify or exported MHX and be sure to enable autorun python scripts in user preferences.