# Problem when importing MHX2 file in Blender 3.1.3

Tags: makehuman

I have this error message that appears when I try to import mhx2 object.
any idea ?
THX a lot

**error message**:

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ignatius III\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\import_runtime_mhx2\importer.py", line 56, in execute
importMhx2File(self.filepath, cfg, context)

File "C:\Users\Ignatius III\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\import_runtime_mhx2\importer.py", line 143, in importMhx2File
struct, time1 = importMhx2Json(filepath)

File "C:\Users\Ignatius III\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\import_runtime_mhx2\importer.py", line 157, in importMhx2Json
time1 = time.clock()

AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

location: :-1

Comment: That's an external addon not part of Blender so you should ask on the addon website. Also make sure that the addon version is correct for the version of Blender which you are using. 3.1.3 is quite old now and unsupported. Blender 3.3.3 LTS is the earliest supported version and 3.4.1 is the current version. You can report issues by clicking the New Issue button on [this](https://github.com/makehumancommunity/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/issues) web page.

Comment: John Eason: Thank you for the answer. I exported my character in FBX format. It works. In fact it is to train me again with the Rig. Does this format work with the Meta Rig? Thanks

Comment: I I'm afraid that I've no idea. I don't really see what that has to do with your original question anyway. Don't know whether [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76352/makehuman-1-1-1-use-mhx2-no-rigify-on-export?rq=1) posting helps?

Comment: Hey - It's just that I'm going back to Blender and I want to practice Rigging on a simple model with the minimum of clothes without too much complexity.

Answer (score 1):

While MHX still exists, it is generally considered deprecated in favor of MPFB (see http://static.makehumancommunity.org/mpfb/faq/differences_between_mpfb2_and_mhx2.html)

This said: the above looks as an incompatibility between the python version used in your modern-day blender and what is expected by MHX. You could check if a newer version of MHX is available in the github repo: https://github.com/makehumancommunity/mhx2-makehuman-exchange and try that to see if the incompatibilities have been solved. There are a few commits which looks as if they could have to do with Blender 3.x.